# xslt apply-templates selects all remaining textnodes

Tags: xslt

I have this simplified xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>1</d>
            <e>2</e>
        </c>
    </b>
    <f>
        <g>3</g>
    </f>
</a>
```

This is the xslt i try to apply:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="c">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="d">

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply this sheet, I get output 2 3, which are the remaining textnodes. I've read about the built-in templates which get applied if it can't find a matching template, but in this case, it should find a template?

What is going on?

**Edit:**

In this case, i would expect to see nothing, because the templates are empty. But i get 2 3 in stead.

Comment: It would help tell what you see and what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `<xsl:template match="d">`, you tell the processor to ignore all nodes under `<d>`.

All other nodes are processed with default rules, including the `text()` one, which is to print the text.

That's why you see 23, and not 1.

Comment: The weird thing is that if i only have one apply-templates, it just works as it's supposed to work. Just selects b node in this example. But as soon as a put another apply-templates, it shows al the textnodes.

Comment: Ah ok, so if i just went on, and specified templates for the other nodes as well, it would just be fixxed?

Comment: If do not want to see any text, do <xsl:apply-template select="b"/> or replace the default rules with <xsl:template match="text()" />.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the root:

```
<xsl:template match="/a">
```

And specify either a mode (so that the default template does not get called, because it does *not* find a template for `e`, `f` and `g`) or define your own * template which does nothing at the end of the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="*"/>
```